# Where is scope name and scope secret for http://demo.identityserver.io/?

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm using http://demo.identityserver.io/ and I'm trying to use the introspection endpoint, but I still got 401 Unauthorized status.
I am using Postman restful client.

```
POST /connect/introspect
Authorization: Basic xxxyyy

token=<token>
```

According to this [doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/endpoints/introspection.html), I need **scope_name** and **scope_secret** to generate Authorization token (xxxyyy). I do not find information for scope name and scope secret at [demo page](http://demo.identityserver.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the API-ID and the API-Secret. Only the API (resource server) is allowed to validate tokens (it wouldn't make sense for a client anyways).

The API-ID and API-Secret are sent base64 in the following format (id:secret) like this:

```
base64("api:secret") = YXBpOnNlY3JldA==
```

Request:

```
POST /connect/introspect HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.identityserver.io
Authorization: Basic YXBpOnNlY3JldA==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

token=xxxyyy
```

Comment: So, I have to setup IdentityServer to test introspect :/. Thanks for your explanation of base64 encoding.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, but you can just download the sample project it's fairly easy to setup.

Comment: Coincidentally - I set it up yesterday. it is api:secret

Comment: @leastprivilege Thank you, I have updated my answer!